# How to open an already opened file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using a library that loads a file using `open(filename)`.

I don't want to mess with the file system, so I tried to download this file in memory using `BytesIO`:

```py
obj = BytesIO(requests(url).content)
```

But, if I pass the `obj` to the library, I'll get an error.

How can I transform my object so it could be "opened" by `open(object)`?

Comment: the library should be adapted to accept a stream in input. On linux it may be possible to use pipe files (and named pipes on windows)...

Comment: A `BytesIO` object is already a proper file-like object so you don't need to "open" it again.

Comment: I know that. But it's not my library. I can't change it.

Comment: @GustavoLopes if you have the source, you can change it

Comment: I now see what you're asking about. Will write up an answer then.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the built-in `open` function to return the first argument directly if the argument is a file-like object (which can be identified if it has a `read` attribute):

```
import builtins
original_open = open
builtins.open = lambda f, *args, **kwargs: f if hasattr(f, 'read') else original_open(f, *args, **kwargs)
```

so that:

```
from io import BytesIO
print(open(BytesIO(b'hello world'), 'rb').read())
```

outputs:

```
b'hello world'
```

Comment: of course, but that means modifying the library that OP doesn't want to modify.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. It changes the builtin `open` function, so it can handle "opening" already opened files (it doesn't open it again, it simply return the stream).

Answer (score -1):

You can't unless you want to save it as a file because the `open()` method can only be used for files contained in the file system. Instead, you can check out the python docs on io streams (found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and learn how to access your data through io methods.

Comment: `BytesIO` is from `io` package. OP is well aware of this module

Comment: I'm aware. I was simply saying that he could find the class methods for BytesIO objects in the docs.